# "Group similar taskbar buttons" not working

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

When I changed orientation Windows task bar and put it to vertical, then "Group similar taskbar buttons" is not working.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Group similar taskbar buttons](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-84234.php) :

> Grouping works in vertical mode too,
>   but it doesn't kick in as quickly
>   because the vertical taskbar can hold
>   more items than the horizontal bar.
>
> Try this: unlock the task bar and
>   reduce the available space for the
>   application entries. Once they start
>   getting squeezed you'll start to see
>   grouping.

Comment: you are right....its working after i opened 15 windows. Main issue is that it will create 2 vertical blocks and only after filling it, it will go for grouping. If there are 2 vertical bars, we can only see icons and nothing else :(. Else we have to deliberately open more windows to enable it and close unneeded windows.

Comment: @Antoops: Mere mortals were not meant to understand the ways of Microsoft and its Programmers.

Answer (score 1):

- Right click on Windows Task Bar (or start) button
- Select properties
- Select Task Bar Tab
- Uncheck “Group similar taskbar buttons"
- reboot the computer
- check “Group similar taskbar buttons"

… the issue should be resolved.

It seams that there are a buffer somewhere and this can flush it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried that on a few XP machines and it doesn't work at the sides. It only works at the top & bottom. I guess this is `Status-by-design`.

Comment: u mean a functionality is not given by xp rite?

Comment: I think Microsoft has deliberately done this because when you move your taskbar to the sides, you have extra space to put more buttons side by side. This is because the height of buttons are much lesser than their width, so there is more space to put them next to each other on the sides. That's what I think Microsoft thinked while designing.